# Make a login form with already set username and pass

Tags: java, android, authentication

My task was to make a login form with already set username and password. That should be linked to button that checks those two inputs. If either of entered values is different to the ones set in the program, Toast should pop up and say that I've entered the wrong username or password. If user entered the correct values, button should lead to another activity. However, I tried entering correct credentials and Toast is appearing again without letting me go to the next activity.

This is XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etUsername"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/username"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etUsername" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:background="@color/yellow_700"
    android:text="@string/enterApp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etPassword" />
```

This is Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnLogin;
    private EditText etUsername;
    private EditText etPassword;
    String username = "bartul";
    String password = "kalinic";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        etUsername = findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        String user = etUsername.getText().toString();
        String pass = etPassword.getText().toString();

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(!user.equals(username) || !pass.equals(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong username or password entered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    etUsername.setText("");
                    etPassword.setText("");
                }
                else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MiNoteMenuActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: If it crashes, show the logcat, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move both usages of `getText().toString()` into the onClick method body as the input fields shouldn't have any text to get *until you click the button* to check them.

By the way, never use plaintext passwords, or hard code them within your app.